# How can I simplify this PHP/MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query2  = "select * from dvdcollector where situatie='goedgekeurd'";
$query2  .= " and regisseur = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['regisseur']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or titel like '%". escapeQuote($result->fields['titel']) ."%'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs2']) . "'";  
$query2  .= " or acteurs = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs3']) . "'";  
$query2  .= " or acteurs = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs4']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs5']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs6']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs7']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs8']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs9']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs10']) . "'";

$query2  .= " or acteurs2 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs2 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs2']) . "'"; 
$query2  .= " or acteurs2 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs3']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs2 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs4']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs2 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs5']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs2 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs6']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs2 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs7']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs2 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs8']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs2 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs9']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs2 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs10']) . "'";

$query2  .= " or acteurs3 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs3 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs2']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs3 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs3']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs3 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs4']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs3 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs5']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs3 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs6']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs3 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs7']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs3 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs8']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs3 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs9']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs3 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs10']) . "'";

$query2  .= " or acteurs4 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs4 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs2']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs4 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs3']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs4 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs4']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs4 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs5']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs4 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs6']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs4 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs7']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs4 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs8']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs4 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs9']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs4 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs10']) . "'";

$query2  .= " or acteurs5 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs5 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs2']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs5 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs3']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs5 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs4']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs5 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs5']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs5 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs6']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs5 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs7']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs5 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs8']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs5 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs9']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs5 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs10']) . "'";

$query2  .= " or acteurs6 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs6 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs2']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs6 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs3']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs6 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs4']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs6 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs5']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs6 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs6']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs6 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs7']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs6 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs8']) . "'"; 
$query2  .= " or acteurs6 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs9']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs6 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs10']) . "'";

$query2  .= " or acteurs7 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs7 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs2']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs7 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs3']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs7 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs4']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs7 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs5']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs7 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs6']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs7 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs7']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs7 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs8']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs7 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs9']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs7 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs10']) . "'";

$query2  .= " or acteurs8 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs8 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs2']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs8 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs3']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs8 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs4']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs8 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs5']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs8 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs6']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs8 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs7']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs8 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs8']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs8 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs9']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs8 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs10']) . "'";

$query2  .= " or acteurs9 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs9 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs2']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs9 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs3']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs9 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs4']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs9 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs5']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs9 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs6']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs9 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs7']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs9 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs8']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs9 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs9']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs9 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs10']) . "'";

$query2  .= " or acteurs10 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs10 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs2']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs10 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs3']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs10 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs4']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs10 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs5']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs10 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs6']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs10 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs7']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs10 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs8']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs10 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs9']) . "'";
$query2  .= " or acteurs10 = '". escapeQuote($result->fields['acteurs10']) . "'";
$query2  .= " order by RAND()";
```

Comment: First you remove the `order by RAND()`.

Comment: You should change you DB design. It seems you have hardcoded something for up to 10 actors. Having to tables and a foreign key relation ship is probably better...

Comment: Please provide more context regarding *what you are trying to do*. Simply posting a query and asking people to simplify is a bit.. simplistic.

Comment: @Felix "probably!" I love that "probably". 2 x 2 would be 4 *probably*, my foot!

Comment: That is a *lot* of -2 answers.

Comment: a WTF candidate if I ever saw one :P

Comment: Time to ask for close reason: Off Topic: Belongs on http://thedailywtf.com

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT**: now with more tables!

First of all it seems to me that the design is flawed. If I understand right you used the fields to list the actors' names:

```
movieId | actor | actor 2 | actor 3 | actor 4
```

This is bad for so many reasons. You may want to start reading about [normalization in databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

You'd better split this into three tables:

```
movies > movieId | movieTitle
actors > actorId | actorName
cast > movieId (fk to movies.movieId) | actorId (fk to actors.actorId)
```

Example:

```
movies > movieId:=123 | movieTitle:='Big Fish'
movies > movieId:=124 | movieTitle:='Matrix'
actors > actorId:=555 | actorName:='Ewan McGregor'
actors > actorID:=777 | actor:='Keanu Reeves'
actors > actorID:=888 | actor:='Lawrence Fishburne'
cast> actorId:=123 | movieId:=123
cast> actorId:=555 | movieId:=124
cast> actorId:=888 | movieId:=124
```

Then your query would look something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM movies JOIN cast ON cast.movieId=movies.movieID 
    JOIN cast JOIN actors ON actors.actorId = cast.actorID
WHERE actors.actorName = 'the_actor'
```

Post scriptum: random order in queries is a bit of an anti-pattern as well, see [SQL Antipatters by Bill Karwin](http://pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/sql-antipatterns).

Comment: +1 for the example. Looks like the OP is using actor names as well... better to have a separate actors table too, with the name and an actor_id, and make the xref table based purely on ids

Comment: Yes, I thought of that as well right after pressing the submit button.

Comment: Actually he needs 3 tables, unless you want to keep repeating all actor info for every movie (s)he plays in. So you need `movie`, `actor` and `movieactor`, with the last one just containing a movie-id and actor-id. **note to self** read other comments first :p.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you forgot to normalize a this table. Acteur is definately a repeating group. I suggest you normalize this now before the headage even gets worse.

If you don't want to do this, use `where IN('')` statements and use a select in that statement.

Answer (score 2):

CRIKEY!!!

You need 3 tables...

table 1: dvd
table 2: acteur

table 3: dvd_acteur

NOW if you need one record from your query GROUP_CONCAT will help...

```
SELECT dvd.*, GROUP_CONCAT(`acteur`.`Name` SEPARATOR ',')
FROM dvd
LEFT JOIN dvd_acteur ON dvd_acteur.dvdID = dvd.dvdID
LEFT JOIN acteur ON acteur.acteurID = dvd_acteur.acteurID
WHERE dvd.situatie = 'goedgekeurd'
GROUP BY dvd.dvdID
```

see how that goes.

Answer (score -3):

using IN()

```
select * from dvdcollector where situatie='goedgekeurd'
...
and (acteurs in(acteurs1, acteurs2, ...) or
acteurs2 in(acteurs1, acteurs2, ...) or
acteurs3 in(acteurs1, acteurs2, ...)
)
```

Answer (score -4):

You need to look into using loops: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping.asp .

Once you've got the hang of that, learn some mysql best practises: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/

You may also want to look at your database design and consider adding some kind of attribute to you Actors... For example SELECT FROM actors WHERE acting_style = 'method acting'

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in for example :)

Comment: Uh, why not link to the official documentation? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: w3school link because, this guys clearly a major beginner and it can be more accessible for the basics. And i stress only the basics.

Comment: @Raffael1984 I don't like w3 schools very much either but I do understand it might be more accesible to beginners, unpenetrable information to newbies is what's making this kind of imprecise simplified sites so popular

Comment: @Trufa: that's actually a good rationale for posting a specific, simplified example *here*...

Comment: @Shog9 good point actually... But I don't think the user deserved 5 down-votes for mentioning that Site-Which-Must-Not-Be-Named.

Comment: @Trufa: Personally, I find it lacking in general - yes, the OP has some learning to do, but he didn't ask for that *here*. You could post links in a comment and avoid the pretense of actually answering the question.  I would probably just vote to delete it, but one person thinks it's useful so I won't.

Comment: @Shog9 Again, good point. Agreed, the links could/should have been a comment. I just found it a bit an exaggerated reaction, thats all.

Comment: @Trufa: some of us have been... *Irritated* by w3schools for quite a few years now, and our patience is starting to wear thin. When you're used to seeing folks show up on SO with problems *caused* by w3schools-sourced misinformation, seeing it recommended to users who *don't* know enough to recognize the flaws starts to seem... almost abusive. Personally, I think Haroldo's intentions were good, but it sets a bad tone (and then mostly fails to counter it by addressing the question).